# Does the Operations Training Dummy hit back?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Through my legacy I can unlock a Training Dummy that simulates combat within an operation.

Now for a DPS Character it might be enough to test damage, but for me as tank it would be important to know if this dummy actually hits me back before I spend 500.000 Credits to unlock it.

[image: Screenshot of unlock]

Can anyone who bought this unlock answer that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

The dummy is equivelant to what you can find on the fleet ship. It just has the sort of resistances, armour stats, etc. that you could expect to find on a mob in Operations, so that you can estimate / tune your build for DPS.